# How to not stretch an image in UIButton

Tags: ios, cocoa, uibutton

I'm trying to create a custom UITableViewCell programmatically and one of the subviews of this cell is going to be a button with an image in it (a simple image of a magnifying glass). However, I want the button's image to be centered and scaled proportionately down to fit in the button and NOT to be stretched to fill the entire button.  Below is my code where self refers to the custom UITableViewCell which I am placing the button into.

```
self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @image_name_here"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(...//something, something)
self.myButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.mySearchHelpButton];
```

Right now the image stretches to fill the entire button rather than scaling proportionately so that it fits nicely.

I have also tried setting the contentMode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` but this doesn't seem to change anything. In fact, none of the different contentModes seem to change anything.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Have you tried `setImage` instead of `setBackgroundImage`?

Answer (score 58):

Make sure the button is a Custom UIButton

Just using `setImage:` did not work for me on iOS9.

But it worked combined with `myButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;`

Comment: Thanks! This works for me too, seems to me this attribute is not exposed in IB, so that we have to manually set it in code instead of from IB. On IB, there is only a content mode setting for the button itself, instead of its imageView. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're spot on RainCast - the only way to set aspect fit for just the imageView seems to be programmatically.

Answer (score 46):

In Swift...

```
button.imageView?.contentMode = . scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: this is now `button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

Comment: keep in mind if `yourButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`then `.scaleAspectFit` will not be applied

Answer (score 38):

## Storyboard

**Property** image.

You must define specific property in **Runtime Attributes** of **Identity inspector** – `imageView.contentMode`, where you set value relatively to `rawValue` position of enum `UIViewContentMode`. 1 means **scaleAspectFit**.

[image: Set button.imageView.contentMode in Storyboard]

And button's alignment, in **Attributes inspector**:

[image: Full alignment of button]

Comment: thank you, your guide helps me a lot. is it possible for you to give me a brief explanation about what are you doing exactly? thank you very much

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh could you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: this way is working completely fine for button which I want to but what If I have a imageView then I need my picture clip to bounds and also no stretch with full image shown

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh `clipToBounds` and `scaleAspectFit` are right for this. If it's not what you are talking – create a question and put a link here. But put question for images of expected result.

Comment: This is the rawValue of the scaleAspectFit enum (case scaleAspectFit = 1)

Comment: This worked for me, but ONLY after I had unloaded and reloaded the image - ie delete the image name from the image / background image field, then add it again to reload.

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: out of all this worked for me... none of the other solutions workd

Comment: thank you, I had this issue when used several buttons in UIStackView, and it helped

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4.2**

```
myButton.imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

**Swift earlier version**

```
myButton.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.X and 5.X**

```
button.imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you guys are missing the obvious issue. The image is too large for the button and iOS then has to guess how you want to scale it. Make sure your images are the right size and you won't have this issue. Of course this is for static images and buttons that you know the size for up-front -- not dynamic content.

Comment: What would be the right size for a normal button? less than the width and height of the button itself? or how it is calculated?

Comment: @tyoc213, the size should be exactly the point size of the button, width and height, that you want. For example if you want a 44pt x 100pt button, the image asset should be 44x100 pixels @ 1x, 88x200 pixels @ 2x, 132x300 pixels @ 3x.That way auto layout knows can use the image as the intrinsic size of the button.