# Make navigation button bigger

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, image-scaling

I have a custom icon on my navigation bar and even when i set the size to 600 x 400 it still shows to small on the bar.

[image]
My code for it is :

```
-(void)goBackOne {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIButton *backbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    backbtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 25);
    [backbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goBackOne) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backbtn];//set new button
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;//hide original back button


}
```

Comment: pls check [UIImage imageNamed:@"done_button.png"] size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your frame is 35x25 (`...frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 25)`), it doesn't matter if your picture is 4096x2160.

You have a few options.

You could set the picture to the proper size and:

```
UIImage buttonImage* = [UIImage imageNamed:@"done_button.png"]; // png size ~40x40 for retina
backbtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
```

or manually set the frame with an obvious

```
backbtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 35);
```

and programmatically make your UIImage to scale or stretch inside the frame bounds. [Stretch a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623961/stretch-background-image-for-uibutton).

also you could try implementing a normal back button through storyboard/xibs and simply call `setImage` if you don't mind letting Objective-C do the heavy lifting. (see: [How not to stretch an image for UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346697/how-to-not-stretch-an-image-in-uibutton?rq=1))