# How to avoid distort and stretch image in Custom UIButton while using vector image set?

Tags: ios, xcode

Below is my storyboard, I had quite a lot of constrains to make those four buttons fit into the screen nicely. However, after I put the images into the buttons and check the storyboard preview, all images are distorted. I try to adjust (had tried all of the options) the view mode at attribute inspector panel but seems no effect at all.

One more thing, I am using PDF as **vector type** image set, not regular `.png` file I am wonder if that matters? Should I change the way vector image displayed inside UIButton programaticly?

The verctor image size was 500px*500px. I resize the image into 50px*50px after @orkenstein 's reminader, xcode may not be able to handle oversized vector image that well. The image appear inside button as it is exactly 50px*50px and lost its ability to scale. Also as he sugested I should but the vector image inside an `UIImageView` and after my test, it works perfectly fine in an `UIImageView`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `Aspect Fit` and `Aspect Fill`. This will preserve original aspect ratio.

Comment: I had tried all of them and no effect.

Comment: Where do you set you images?

Comment: What do you mean? I put my image inside `Images.xcassets`. Set the view mode at attribute inspector panel while button selected.

Comment: You set your vector images as `UIButton`'s `background image` or `image`?

Comment: I also tried both either set the image as `Image` OR `Background` OR `Image AND Background`, NO effect. Is that because I am using vector image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70918/discussion-between-orkenstein-and-x-li).

Comment: Did u found the solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Setting the `contentMode` on the button itself doesn't work for me, but setting  it on the button's `imageView` does. From [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34203106/2067021):

```
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```